# How do I turn off echo in a terminal?

Tags: unix, terminal, sh

I'm writing a Bourne shell script and have a password input like this:

```
echo -n 'Password: '
read password
```

Obviously, I don't want the password being echoed to the terminal, so I want to turn off echo for the duration of the read. I know there's way to do this with `stty`, but I'll ask the question for the benefit of the community whilst I go read the manpage. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a password from a shell script without echoing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
stty_orig=`stty -g`
stty -echo
echo 'hidden section'
stty $stty_orig
```

Comment: This is certainly the way I've done it before, if memory serves. Just out of curiosity, is this any different from `stty -echo; read foo; stty echo`?

Comment: Yes, it leaves echo switched off afterwards in case it had been switched off already.

Comment: i am new to unix. Could u explain about what exactly stty and what this  code is doing

Comment: More general, better than Wikipedia when you're new to unix @AbhishekGupta: 1. learn how to scroll, search, and quit `less` (or `more`). 2. `man whateveryouwonderabout` or, for bash builtin commands such as "set", `help set`. Good luck on your journey ;-)

Answer (score 17):

`read -s password` works on my linux box.

Comment: This is useful information but -s seems to be a Bash extension, as `read -s foo` produces `read: 1: Illegal option -s` in Dash (the Bourne shell which Ubuntu symlinks to `/bin/sh`).

Comment: Works in zsh and bash

Answer (score 6):

You can use **'-s' option of read** command to hide user input.

```
echo -n "Password:"
read -s password
if [ $password != "..." ]
then
        exit 1; # exit as password mismatched #
fi
```

Also you can use ***'stty -echo'*** if you want to hide from terminal to print. And restore the terminal settings using ***"stty echo"***

But I think for getting password input from user ***'read -s password'*** is more than enough.

Comment: It's stty, not ssty.

Answer (score 0):

**Bourne Shell Script :**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Prompt user for Password
echo -n 'Password: '

# Do not show what is being typed in console by user
stty -echo

# Get input from user and assign input to variable password
read password

# Show what is being typed in console
stty echo
```

**stty manual command for more information:**

```
@:/dir #man stty
```

**stty manual snippets:**

```
 STTY(1)              stty 5.2.1 (March 2004)              STTY(1)

     NAME
          stty - change and print terminal line settings

     SYNOPSIS
          stty [-F DEVICE] [--file=DEVICE] [SETTING]...
          stty [-F DEVICE] [--file=DEVICE] [-a|--all]
          stty [-F DEVICE] [--file=DEVICE] [-g|--save]

     DESCRIPTION
          Print or change terminal characteristics.

          -a, --all
               print all current settings in human-readable form

          -g, --save
               print all current settings in a stty-readable form

          -F, --file=DEVICE
               open and use the specified DEVICE instead of stdin

          --help
               display this help and exit

          --version
               output version information and exit

          Optional - before SETTING indicates negation.  An * marks
          non-POSIX settings.  The underlying system defines which
          settings are available.



   Local settings:

          [-]echo
               echo input characters
```