# How to turn off local echo when using Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using Paramiko to connect to remote Cisco routers and switches. When connecting to these devices, I'd like to be able to turn off echo when entering "configuration" mode. That way, I can issue commands to the remote system and avoid seeing them come back (and thereby concentrate only on looking for error messages).

I'm performing the following commands to get a shell with the Cisco device:

```
    self.chan = self.transport.open_session()
    self.chan.get_pty()
    self.chan.invoke_shell()
```

Now, I'd like to be able to take paramiko's file descriptor for the pty and issue something like the following:

```
    fd = self.chan.fileno()
    old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    old[3] = old[3] | termios.ECHO
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
```

However, *termios* chokes on the file-descriptor returned by chan.fileno().

Most [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633472/how-do-i-turn-off-echo-in-a-terminal) for turning off echo that I have seen require issuing a bash command like "stty -echo" on the remote box, but a Cisco router is not running bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time with this, I ended up going back to the [pxssh](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pxssh.html) library. This library explicitly has a way to turn echo off:

```
    connection.setecho(False)
```

...which was exactly what I needed. It also (via the parent module, [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html)) has a way to deal with telnet using the exact same library infrastructure (which unfortunately is still necessary often in the Cisco world), so you can have a connection object that uses telnet or ssh and it works in exactly the same way.

Whereas Paramiko seems like a much cleaner, better maintained library, the consensus in the Paramiko community seems to be that if you want to stop echo you need to tell the remote system not to echo. But when the remote system is not a linux/bash process, that becomes difficult or impossible. Pxssh is the library you need for more fine-grained control of your ssh session.