# How can I disable duplicate command entries in CMD while using Paramiko interactive shell?

Tags: python, cmd, paramiko

So, I'm a beginner with Python and I'm mostly building an SSH client for fun and working on a little automation for repetitive tasks at work. The script works as intended right now except for one minor annoyance - the entered command shows up twice in command prompt and powershell (but for some reason it doesn't when running the script in Pycharm)

CMD response:

```
FortiGate-60F # sh sys admin
sh sys admin
config system admin
    edit "admin"
        set accprofile "super_admin"
        set vdom "root"
    next
end
```

PyCharm response:

```
FortiGate-60F # sh sys admin

config system admin
    edit "admin"
        set accprofile "super_admin"
        set vdom "root"
    next
end
```

Full script (un/pw redacted):

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import colorama

colorama.init()


def shell(chan):
    import threading

    def writeall(sock):
        decoder = ""
        while True:
            data = sock.recv(256)
            decoder = str(data.decode("utf8", "ignore"))
            if not data:
                sys.stdout.write("\r\n*** DISCONNECTED ***\r\n\r\n")
                sys.stdout.flush()
                remote_conn.close()
                sys.exit()
            sys.stdout.write(decoder)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            if "Type the hot key to suspend the connection: <CTRL>Z" in decoder:
                sys.stdout.write(f"\r\033[1F\033[2KType the hot key to suspend the connection: <CTRL>C\n\n")

    writer = threading.Thread(target=writeall, args=(chan,))
    writer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            d = sys.stdin.readline()
            if d == "set_phone_home\n":
                chan.send("\rexec batch start\n")
                time.sleep(.5)
                chan.send("config system central-management\n")
                time.sleep(.5)
                chan.send("set type fortimanager\n")
                time.sleep(.5)
                chan.send("set serial-number \"FMG-VM0A16000497\"\n")
                time.sleep(.5)
                chan.send("set fmg \"172.85.135.226\"\n")
                time.sleep(.5)
                chan.send("end\n")
                time.sleep(.5)
                chan.send("exec batch end\n")
            elif d == "firmware_up\n":
                chan.send("\rexecute restore image usb image.out\n")
                sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
                time.sleep(.5)
                chan.send("y")
            elif d == "quit_ssh\n":
                remote_conn.close()
                sys.exit()
            else:
                chan.send(d)




    except EOFError:
        # user hit ^Z or F6
        remote_conn.close()
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        remote_conn.close()
        sys.exit()


def get_serv():
    global serv
    serv = input("COM: ")
    try:
        serv = int(serv)
    except:
        get_serv()


def get_portx():
    global portx
    portx = input("Port: ")
    try:
        portx = int(portx)
    except:
        get_portx()


print("\n(╯°□°)╯_- \u001b[31m♥\033[39m FortiSSH Client \u001b[31m♥\033[39m\n")

serv = 0
portx = 0
serv_list = [17, 18, 19, 200]
while serv not in serv_list:
    get_serv()
while not 0 < portx < 49:
    get_portx()

if serv == 17:
    ip = '192.168.40.17'
    username = 'XXXXXXXX'
    password = 'XXXXXXXX'
    port = "30" + f"{portx:02}"
elif serv == 18:
    ip = '192.168.40.18'
    username = input("User name: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    port = "30" + f"{portx:02}"
elif serv == 19:
    ip = '192.168.40.19'
    username = 'XXXXXXXX'
    password = 'XXXXXXXX'
    port = "22" + f"{portx:02}"
elif serv == 200:
    ip = '192.168.41.200'
    username = 'XXXXXXXX'
    password = 'XXXXXXXX'
    port = "30" + f"{portx:02}"

# username = input("User name: ")
# password = pwinput.pwinput(prompt="Password: ", mask="•")


# port = 3001

# Create instance of SSHClient object
remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Automatically add untrusted hosts (make sure okay for security policy in your environment)
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# initiate SSH connection
remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password, port=port, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
print(f"\nSSH connection established to {ip}, Port {portx}")

# Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
shell(remote_conn)
remote_conn.close()
```

I've tried a few different things, but can't seem to come up with a solution. Please help!

Comment: [How to turn off local echo when using paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912226/how-to-turn-off-local-echo-when-using-paramiko)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did turn echo off in cmd before running the script and got the same result.

Comment: BTW, think about using triple-backtick code formatting instead of four-space indents. The newer format lets you pick what kind of syntax highlighting you want, because you can put a language name right after the opening backticks; `none` for no highlighting, `python` for python, etc; and there's less risk of breaking indentation by mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure `echo off` is the same thing (depends on implementation details -- specifically, whether the feedback is done by the shell or the terminal itself; it's the terminal version we want to disable, disabling only the shell one -- which I _suspect_ is what `echo off` does -- won't do anything), but honestly, I know UNIX terminals better than I know the Windows one, so I'm not a good person to speak authoritatively here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the tips. The link you provided looks like it might do the trick. It seems like pxssh may be a better alternative. I'll give it a shot this afternoon.