# why does it wrap without endl;?

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ beginner and I just wrote this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int readNumber()
{
    cout << "Insert a number: ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

void writeAnswer(int x)
{
    cout << "The sum is: " << x << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x = readNumber();
    int y = readNumber();
    int z = x + y;
    writeAnswer(z);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the output is like this:

```
Insert a number: 3
Insert a number: 4
The sum is: 7
```

and not like:

```
Insert a number: 3Insert a number: 4The sum is: 7
```

since in the `readNumber` function there is no `endl;`.

What am I missing?

(Of course I'm happy with the result I get, but it's unexpected for me)

Comment: When you've typed a number, do you press Enter?

Comment: You type `3` and hit enter. Your console doesn't send the input to the program until you hit enter. The output is interleaving with what you typed. Try typing "3 4<enter>".

Comment: As for knowledge I recommend you to try [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed) as an experiment.

Comment: @jblixr since this is beginners question, may get confused with given link.

Comment: This is a good, well-posed _beginner_ question. I like seeing questions like this. +1 for the input, expected output, and code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's because you push <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you enter numbers (-:

First two lines of your "output" aren't pure output. It's mixed with input.

Answer (score 4):

The terminal has a feature/option called echo where it is showing the input as you type. It is by default enabled and causes your own presses of Enter to show up as a newline. In fact, if you had appended an `endl` after each input, this would have resulted in a blank line appearing after each number. On GNU and many UNIX systems, echo can be disabled using

```
$ stty -echo
```

Be careful with this command as you will not be able to see the next commands you are typing (`stty echo` or `reset` can be used to enable echo again).

For more information, see this question: [How do I turn off echo in a terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633472/how-do-i-turn-off-echo-in-a-terminal)

Comment: While the accepted answer is clear and correct, this one really gets to the bottom of things. Because otherwise there's still, "But why does `Enter` generate a newline, anyway?"--and that's ultimately related to the terminal device itself, rather than just the user's pressing buttons.