# How to create a navigation menu in dotnet application?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, console, systemd

I have created a console application which have a menu that allow me to navigate between the menu items. I handle the navigation logic in this method:

```
public virtual void updateMenu()
{
    switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
            {
                if (cursor > 0)
                {
                    cursor--;
                    Console.Clear();
                    drawWithHeader();
                }
            }
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
            {
                if (cursor < (menuItemList.Count - 1))
                {
                    cursor++;
                    Console.Clear();
                    drawWithHeader();
                }
            }
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.Escape:
            {
                if (ParentMenu != null)
                {

                    hideMenu();
                }
            }
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.Enter:
            {
                Console.Clear();
                drawHeader();
                Console.CursorVisible = true;
                menuItemList[cursor].Action();
                Console.CursorVisible = false;
                Console.Clear();
                drawWithHeader();
            }
            break;
        default:
            {
                // Unsuported key. Do nothing....
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

[here the full class](https://pastebin.com/SpkmCBnq).

Now on windows all works well, but when I run this application on my linux with `systemd` I get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read key when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.

The stacktrace display:

```
at System.ConsolePal.ReadKey(Boolean intercept)
at System.Console.ReadKey();
at AppRazen.Menu.ConsoleMenu.UpdateMenu();
```

After some searching I discovered that this problem is related to the `ReadKey()` method is not fully [compatible with linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655517/why-is-net-core-handling-readkey-differently-on-raspbian). And the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901071/readkey-not-working-in-net-core) simply doesn't work in my case, because the user has used `OminSharp`.

I also tried to set `ReadKey(false)` but this didn't fixed the problem, and I also tried to handle all the stuff inside `UpdateMenu` with `Console.Read()` but the console seems stuck.

Note that this issue will happen only when I run my script in linux supervisor not with the default command like `dotnet AppRazen.dll`

Essentially I'm running the script with a `systemd` service like this:

```
[Unit]
Description = Daemon description

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/bin/dotnet /home/root/Desktop/publish/AppRazen.dll
WorkingDirectory= /home/root/Desktop/publish
Restart = always
RestartSec = 3

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I honestly I don't know how can I fix that. Someone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to doing what you want to do is that you simply can't.

Think about it: you are trying to have an interactive program (that users can interact with via the keyboard). But you are also making it a daemon (a deamon runs the background and doesn't interact with users directly). These are two contradictory goals.

When `systemd` (or `supervisord`, or `upstart` or really any system services program) runs your application as a service, it doesn't give it a way to interact with users, since these applications want to be daemons - which means users can't interact with them.

So, ask yourself what you want to do: do you want to make an interactive program or not? If you want make an interactive program you can't run it via supervisor. Run it directly, via `dotnet /path/to/your.dll`.

Other comments:

- `ReadKey` may have issues, but certainly not in the common case that you are drying to do, which seems to be Linux on x86_64.
- OmniSharp is a plugin for IDEs/text-editors to make development easier. It provides auto completion and real time syntax highlighting. It's not involved when you are running your application.