# How does ssh receive password from tty?

Tags: linux, ssh, tty, pty, sshpass

I was wondering how openssh gets the password when login, cause I got stuck in automating entering passwords to the similar tools in linux which requires getting password from tty like ssh.

Tried to understand sshpass and found that sshpass forks a child process with the same pid then enters the password under the child process.

Don't know if my guess was right that ssh needs to check the right pid since I cannot stdin to the current tty using another process to enter the ssh password.

Comment: It doub that anyone can fork a process with the same pid on any Unix.

Comment: This explains how to turn echo off in a terminal to read a password: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633472/how-do-i-turn-off-echo-in-a-terminal

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, many programs requires a password interactively from users.
Quite many programs uses the following kind of check before reading a password from stdin:

```
if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO) == 0)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

So the program allows password only from a terminal. That way it try to prevent non-interactive password entering.

sshpass is just a tool for:

> fooling ssh into thinking it is getting the password from an interactive user. [from man page of sshpass]

For fooling `ssh`, `sshpass` creates and open a pseudo terminal, and gives that for stdin of `ssh`. `fork()` is needed because `sshpass` must write a password to `ssh` via the pseudo terminal.

This way `stdin` of `ssh` process is a terminal, and `isatty` test will be passed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think my expression is not very accurate and clear about the question. And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415122/what-causes-read-in-c-does-not-read-content-that-being-input-by-other-proc) is the exact problem I got, plz take a glance.