# What causes `read()` in `c` does not read content that being input by other processes from the current `tty`?

Tags: c, linux, openssh, tty

I imitated the check-password module from openssh source code and it uses `read()` to get the content from the current tty's file descriptor, here is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main ()   
{   
    int ttyfd=open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
    if(ttyfd>=0)
        printf("good to open\n");

    char * a;
    while(read (ttyfd,a,1)){
        printf("%s", a);
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

It runs in a terminal like this:

```
root@localhost:~/Desktop# tty
/dev/pts/0
root@localhost:~/Desktop# ./a.out 
good to open
11111111111
11111111111
^C
root@localhost:~/Desktop#
```

While the other terminal sending strings redirecting to the first one like:

```
root@localhost:~# echo 11111111111 >> /dev/pts/0
root@localhost:~# echo 11111111111 >> /dev/pts/0
```

But `read()` does not actually works when there is another process wants to input. So what causes `read()` in `c` does not read content that being input by other processes from the current `tty`?

Perhaps I expressed not very clear in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55351259/how-does-ssh-receive-password-from-tty), but it is the same question I get stuck.

Comment: You have a pointer `a`, but *where does it point?*

Comment: And don't forget that strings needs to be *null-terminated*. It seems to me that you just want to read a single `char` and print a single `char` as well. Also don't forget that `read` returns `-1` on error, which is a "true" value.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the source code of `sshpass` fo how to do what you seem to want.