# I want to have raw_input and nohup together in python

Tags: python

I am dealing with a large data set and it takes some days to run, therefore I use nohup to run my script in terminal. 
This time I need to first get a raw_input from terminal then by nohup, my codes starts running. Any suggestion how I can do that?

so first I need to get input from terminal like this

```
$ python myprogram.py 
enter_input: SOMETHING
```

then the process should be like this:

```
$nohup python myprogram.py &
```

But I want to do this in one step via terminal. I hope my explanation is clear :)

Comment: you explanation wasn't clear. i think you want sys.argv though. but i think you can do it with something like `nohup python myprogram.py raw_input` then access it with `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: yes, it works by introducing sys.argv[1] in the code and in terminal I enter: $ nohup python myprogram.py SOMTHING & By this SOMETHING will be input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't your program have read input from stdin, but give it data via its command line.

So instead of

```
startdata = raw_input('enter_input:')
```

you do

```
import sys
startdata = sys.argv[1]
```

and you start your program with

```
$ nohup python myprogram.py SOMETHING &
```

and all works the way you want - if I get you right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more option, in case you want to stick with the user-friendly nature of the input box. I did something like this because I needed a password field, and didn't want the user to have to display their password in the terminal. [As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing), you can create a small wrapper shell script with input boxes (with or without the -s option to hide), and then pass those variables via the sys.argv solution above. Something like this, saved in an executable my_program.sh:

```
echo enter_input:
read input

echo enter_password:
read -s password

nohup python myprogram.py $username $password &
```

Now, running `./my_program.sh` will behave exactly like your original `python my_program.py`

Comment: huh. there is a problem though. when we do ps grep, we can see password in process details.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your process [fork to the background after reading the input](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/).  The by far easier variant, though, is to start your process inside [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/).