# password hiding in shell

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting . i want to make the password not visible when we type password ..can you please suggest me on this

> echo "enter your password"
>
> read pass
>
> if [ "$pass" != "" ]
>
> then
>
> echo "thank you "
>
> else
>
> echo "invalid  password"
>
> exit
>
> fi

Comment: Can you format your source code?

Comment: Using an expect script serves your purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, if you issue in your bash prompt:

```
help read
```

You will find out that you can use a switch.

```
 -s                do not echo input coming from a terminal
```

Thus simply using `read -s pass` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
# turn echo off
stty -echo

...

# turn echo back on
stty echo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
read -sp pass
```

this should help.