# What does "stty raw -echo" do on OS X

Tags: bash, stty

When I try: `$ stty raw -echo` on my Terminal (Bash on OS X 10.6). It does stringe things and it's like the terminal hang there. Then I lookup the manual:

> ### stty — set the options for a terminal device interface
>
> **raw (-raw)**
>
> If set, change the modes of the terminal so that no input or
>   output processing is performed.  If unset, change the modes   of the
>   terminal to some reasonable state that performs input   and output
>   processing.  Note that since the terminal driver   no longer has a
>   single RAW bit, it is not possible to intuit   what flags were set
>   prior to setting raw. This means that   unsetting raw may not put back
>   all the setting that were   previously in effect. To set the terminal
>   into a raw state and   then accurately restore it, the following shell
>   code is recommended:
>
> ```
> save_state=$(stty -g)
> stty raw
> ...
> stty "$save_state"
> ```
>
> **echo (-echo)**
>
> Echo back (do not echo back) every character typed.

So it's supposed to turn the Terminal in raw mode then return what I type in as is? Could someone please explain what does this command do? And what is the difference when an argument has dash, e.g. `raw` and `-raw`? Are they mean the samething? Is there any resource I could learn this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Firstly, the dash means "disable" a setting. So this enables echoing:

```
stty echo
```

This disables it:

```
stty -echo
```

When you disable it, your typing is not echoed back to you, which is why it seems as if the terminal is hanging. Try `stty -echo` then type `ls` and press return - you will still see the output of `ls`.

The `raw` setting means that the input and output is not processed, just sent straight through. Processing can be things like ignoring certain characters, translating characters into other characters, allowing interrupt signals etc. So with `stty raw` you can't hit Ctrl-C to end a process, for example.