# python3 messes up terminal

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

I'm in Mac OS X 10.10, using `python3` installed using Macports.

There is something really strange going on when I start the interactive `python3` shell. When starting `python3` and runs *anything* (even non-syntactical commands), something happens to the terminal such that

1. I cannot see any newlines while hitting Enter
2. Anything I write doesn't show while typing, but will still be executed when hitting Enter.

This problem persists in the underlying `bash` shell, after closing the `python3` shell (using e.g. Ctrl-D). What makes this even "funnier" is that starting regular `python` afterwards (version 2.7 by the way), the problem solves itself – the terminal behaves as it should.

Has anyone seen this, has any suggestion what might have happened and hopefully knows a way to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in Python 3.4.3, installed on Mac OS 10.10.5 via Homebrew.

Comment: @Jubobs No, I know it's hard to reproduce – either one has a problem with this, or one doesn't… Hopefully, someone might recognize the behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, I see this problem too using python3.5 on Mac OS X 10.10.

This seems to be a bug with the python3 interactive shell - it disables echo for your terminal and does not enable it when you exit().  To fix your terminal, run this command at the bash prompt.

```
stty echo
```

Credit goes to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832933/what-does-stty-raw-echo-do-on-os-x).

**UPDATE:**
This bug is tracked here: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48807
The permanent fix is to install the port py35-readline.

```
sudo port install py35-readline
```

Comment: Is there a bug open anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your terminal, run this command at the bash prompt

```
stty sane
```

Credit goes to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/983755/os-x-terminal-behaves-oddly-after-running-python-interactively)