# Any ideas how to replace os.system("stty echo") to work in windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, stty

A friend of mine wrote python code on a Mac, and now I'm trying to get it to work on a windows laptop.

This line in particular is being annoying:

```
os.system("stty echo")
```

Anyone know a windows equivalent? I've already replaced tty with msvcrt, but I am completely stuck on this.

Comment: You should explain what the command does: `stty echo` since many users do not know what it does.

Comment: Can your friend tell you what the purpose, value, need of that particular snippet is?  And then see if something comparable exists?  Also, it may be better to use `subprocess` when interacting with the os than `os.system`

Comment: Look for `echo on` on windows?

Comment: Was the console's [`ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) mode disabled at some point? If not, you should be able to omit this line. Otherwise you'll need ctypes or PyWin32 to call `GetConsoleMode` and `SetConsoleMode`.

Comment: @lagom, the CMD shell's `echo` command has nothing to do with the console echoing input. The closest the Windows command line has to stty is mode.com, but it only controls a small subset of console modes for compatibility with old batch scripts.

Comment: Explanation of `stty echo`: [What does "stty raw -echo" do on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22837780/411282)

Answer (score 1):

Ended up finding a solution a couple hours later. I added a function to the code that checked if it was a unix of windows computer, and then used msvcrt when needed as a replacement.

I believe I used the code from here to fix the program: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892-getch-like-unbuffered-character-reading-from-stdin/