# Linux: Illegal option read -a

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have found the answer for this question... Just want to provide some information for others, who met this problem too...

In my system, I got this problem because of I used the `sh main.sh` to process my shell script and ignore the difference between "Bash" and "Shell".

In order to solve this problem, you might try to change the mode into executable, by using `chmod +x` and using `./` to execute the program.

Good luck!

Comment: I am happy you was able to make your script working. On the other hand I am afraid that such "question" will not be perceived well by the StackOverflow community, mainly because the actual "question" part is insufficient. There is mainly the "answer" instead.

Comment: difference between "Bash" and "Shell".? Bash is itself a "Shell" and there are other variations available too.

Answer (score 10):

The error:

```
Illegal option read -a
```

was shown because you were trying to run it in a shell where the `-a` option for `read` isn't defined.

the command `chmod +x script.sh` has nothing to do with it. It just merely gives the script execution permission.

You were trying to run the command in Bourne shell by the command `sh script.sh` and Bourne shell `read` doesn't have the `-a` option for read. It's a Bash feature.

Running with `./` is not quite an answer. You could say at least : run it with `path_to_the_script` because not every time your script will end up in the current directory.

You can run it with `bash main.sh` instead of `sh main.sh`.

Comment: "You can run it with bash main.sh instead of sh main.sh" - This is exactly what I needed. My -sp worked with bash and not sh. Thanks!