# Options for secure connection to mysql from bash script

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a few mysql statements in bash script. The script connects to mysql and does all the required work. But, it gives me a warning

*Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.*

I understand that passwords and usernames must not be used directly in the script, which I have currently done

What other options do I have in order to not have this warning coming up? Can I have a file with the key:value pairs for host,dbname,username and password and then use the file for connection details in the script?

Answer (score 0):

During the init phase of your script, I would ask the user for host, username and password. Then forward these variables to the mysql command.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980904/4473044%20here) where you can learn how to ask the user for content without echoing it on the terminal window.

Comment: This script will be scheduled. And as per the requirement this does not require user intervention. So, how I automate in this case?

Comment: try this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751352/suppress-warning-messages-using-mysql-from-within-terminal-but-password-written

Comment: Thanks  that helped me . But, I get the Access denied error even after configuring mysql_config_editor.  The link suggests in such cases I must configure in  ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc files. If so, then what is the use of configuring mysql_config_editor ?

Comment: I guess, you're doing something wrong. Actually I have never used mysql-config-editor, but from the number of positive votes, I guess this procedure is fine. Check for updates of your mysql binaries. The method seems free from environment configs, thus I guess no extra .profile, or .bashrc is required

Comment: Sure ,thank you. I will check the updates. When you said, you are not using mysql_config_editor, how are you handling loading mysql credentials from a file?