# Running commands as different user from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have 2 users: usr1 and usr2. Neither is a root user.

usr1 starts a bash script. And from the script, I want to run some commands as usr2.
I understand that the way to do it is:

```
su -l <usr2> -c "command"
```

The issue is with passing the password. These are 2 different users with different privileges, so, skipping the password for usr2 is not an option.

This script can go interactive, and ask the user for the password. Is there a way to do this in bash script ?

Note: I am not an expert with scripting. And I have done some research before asking this question, but I couldnt find a suitable answer.

Comment: Would adding the NOPASSWD option in the sudoers file be an option for you?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Jason: Nope, security is of utmost importance, and skipping the password is a big NO

Comment: @jww thanks for pointing out. I will try other forums

Comment: Isn't the script already prompting for usr2's password when executed interactively? Can you include a MCVE  and terminal transcript?

Comment: You can use echo as suggested on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing)

Comment: @thatotherguy: I have 30-40 commands which needs to be run as usr2, so I want a solution where the scirpt asks the user the password once, and uses it then on when a su command is run

Comment: @eorochena: I saw a post where password is echoed and piped to the su command. But, that post also says that it's not a recommended way to do it.

Comment: @Manoj Use one `su` that runs all the commands then? The easiest way is to put them all in a separate script and run that with `su`. It's true that it's not recommended to echo passwords to `su`, but the primary reason for that is that people hard-code the password in the script and that's strictly worse than not requiring a password.

Comment: @thatotherguy That is a good option which I can look at... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the read [read man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html) command see example below:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -s -p "Enter your password: " pass
echo $pass
```

In that case you will need to use /bin/su -c along with sudo -S

```
#!/bin/bash 

user=$1
read -s -p "Enter pass: " pass
cmd=$(echo $pass|sudo -S <some-command>)
su -c '$cmd' - $user
```

Where user=$1 additional bash argument, in this case the user id for usr2, then jut run it

```
$sudo bash -x ./password.sh <target-user>
```

Comment: The issue is how to use this password for running commands as su -l user

Comment: You can try to use /bin/su along with /usr/bin/sudo, I updated my answer to reflex this but, probably a better approach would be to give to use linux file ownership and permissions to control which user can execute it via groups.