# Getpass() equivalent in bash

Tags: bash

I'm new to Bash and I'm doing a for loop in a script which will ssh onto various servers (all have the same username and password) but is there a way I can bypass the password prompt to save time?

Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/sshpass-non-interactive-ssh-login-shell-script-ssh-password/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a password from a shell script without echoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing)

Comment: Also you might interest yourself in ansible, puppet and ssh-copy-id.

Comment: @KamilCuk again, you misunderstood the question. This is probably a duplicate (asking for sshpass or sth like that) but not of the one you linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password authentication is inferior to public-key authentication security-wise. While you could achieve what you want with `sshpass`, I recommend switching to public key authentication and employ `ssh-agent(1)` to not reenter passphrases everytime.

Here's how you would setup `ssh-agent`:

In `~/.ssh/config` for each server entry add `ForwardAgent yes` field, or if you want to do it globally, just add

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Then employ the `ssh-agent(1)` like this:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
$ ssh-add /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa_1
$ ssh-add /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```