# How can I allow a user to enter a password in a scripted SSH session?

Tags: shell, ssh, pty

I've got a script which needs to do something on a remote system using SSH.  Something of this sort:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -tt $@ sudo ash -c 'echo "8.8.8.8 dns.google.com" >> /etc/hosts'
```

If the user doesn't need to enter a password for sudo to work, this is fine.  But I can't figure out how to allow the user running this script to enter the password for sudo.  Ideas?  The remote shell is busybox's `ash`.

Comment: doesn't it just ask user in the terminal window?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a password from a shell script without echoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing)

Comment: @akostadinov The script as given above doesn't prompt at all, it just gives `sh: can't create /etc/hosts: Permission denied`.

Comment: Sort of.  The extra complexity comes from the layers of quoting.  This works: `echo Password:; read -s password; echo "${password}" | ssh -tt $@ sudo ash -c "'"'echo "8.8.8.8 dns.google.com" >> /etc/hosts'"'"`

Comment: Does the remote host allow you to login as root? That would be simpler than running `sudo` on the remote box.

Comment: Sadly, no.  Yes, I could hack it so that I could log in as root, but it's an embedded system that gets re-installed every time I test it, so it's a lot easier to figure out how to make this work.

Comment: @Tom, but then it is not `sudo` that fails. It wouldn't return such error.