# How to ask a user for password inside a script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

I have this script that i run to connect to a server and I would like to ask the user for the sudo's password like how "sudo" does it without using sudo. I want it to ask for the password every time the script runs.

```
#a command to ask for password(sudo's password) before running the command below
*insert here*

sshpass -p $password ssh $user@$ip
```

Comment: [How to get a password from a shell script without echoing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3980668/3422102) ?

Comment: maybe you can replace *insert here* with "sudo".that will let the script ask password

Comment: Why not just remove `sshpass -p $password` and let `ssh` prompt directly? (and it should be `sshpass -p "$password"`)

Comment: Before running the sshpass do `read password` . This s will store the user input to the password variable and then you can use it in the sshpass command.