# Hiding user input on terminal in Linux script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have bash script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter your username";
read username;

echo "Please enter your password";
read password;
```

I want that when the user types the password on the terminal, it should not be displayed (or something like  *******) should be displayed). How do I achieve this?

Comment: General note just to prevent confusion: this username/password has got nothing to do with the linux username/password - I am just looking for a way to hide the data that user types during "read password".

Comment: Thanks much. One question if someone knows - will this automatically prevent it from going into .bash_history?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a password from a shell script without echoing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing) and [How to make bash script ask for a password ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654009/how-to-make-bash-script-ask-for-a-password) and [How do i put stars into `read`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923435/how-do-i-put-stars-into-read) and others.

Comment: I don't think it will, bash_history only captures your command, what happens after running your command it doesn't capture.

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/read.html

Answer (score 349, accepted):

Just supply -s to your read call like so:

```
$ read -s PASSWORD
$ echo $PASSWORD
```

Comment: To provide context: `-s` displays _nothing_ while the input is typed. (`-s` is a non-POSIX extension, so not all shells support it, such as the `ash` shell that comes with BusyBox; use the `ssty -echo` approach in such shells)

Comment: Best solution. This - I have noticed - is what almost all password blocks use in Linux and Mac.

Comment: By using -s option ,read command sets the text color to the same as the background color. So why cant I copy the text I had entered?

Comment: @electron Nothing in the `man` page actually suggests that `-s` sets the text color to the same as the the background color. It just "echoes silently".

http://ss64.com/bash/read.html

`Silent mode. If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not echoed.`

Comment: @SiGanteng Actually I was reading the book "Linux command line & shell scripting bible" and it is written on page 391 that "The -s option prevents the data entered in the read command from being displayed on the monitor; actually, the data is displayed, but the read command sets the text color to the same as the background color." . But I didn't found anything like this mentioned in the web.

Comment: @electron I tested on my box, not only it doesn't move the cursor, when I try to highlight the line where I typed in my password, I can't seem to paste it later. Both should happen if what the book says is true. I'm guessing maybe a different flavor of shell (I was using bash 4.1.2(1)).

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis yeah but the label is for bash, therefore the solution. There are probably tons of shell variants where this don't work :)

Comment: I get an error with this approach `read: Illegal option -s`

Answer (score 31):

#### Update

In case you want to get fancy by outputting an `*` for each character they type, you can do something like this (using andreas' `read -s` solution):

```
unset password;
while IFS= read -r -s -n1 pass; do
  if [[ -z $pass ]]; then
     echo
     break
  else
     echo -n '*'
     password+=$pass
  fi
done
```

Without being fancy

```
echo "Please enter your username";
read username;

echo "Please enter your password";
stty -echo
read password;
stty echo
```

Comment: It should be `IFS=$'\n'` so that you can actually *finish* typing the password. Otherwise nice; very clever.

Comment: No need to set `IFS=$'\n'` because read's default delimiter is `-d $'\n'`.  The if-statement to break on a nul string, which happens on a newline, is what allows them to finish the password.

Comment: In testing on FreeBSD with bash 3.x I find this not to be the case. Testing on Linux with 3.1.17 yields your results. I haven't got a BSD box handy at the moment but I will try to confirm this tomorrow, just for my own curiosity's sake.

Comment: @Sorpigal: interesting, let me know what you find out. I'm all about portability

Comment: Confirmed. On FreeBSD 7 with bash 3.2.48(1)-release (i386-portbld-freebsd7.0) your version does not terminate on enter. Setting IFS as I described does cause it to do so. On a Debian box with bash 3.1.17 it works as you describe. Could it be a difference in the defaults for `read` between bash 3.1 and 3.2?

Comment: @Sorpigal: I'm going to  guess that's probably the case. What about this line of code, does this work on FreeBSD 7? `while IFS= read -r -d '' -s -n1 pass; do [[ $pass = $'\n' ]] && echo "you hit enter" && break; done`

Comment: With that line I am prompted for input and all normal key presses are ignored but enter, which aborts the loop.

Comment: I've got it. My FreeBSD test was based on the code copied and pasted from your original mistaken edit of lesmana's post, which contains one important difference: you had been passing `read` a `-d ''`. When I retried it later on Linux I used the reposted version. If I try omitting `-d ''` of course it works identically on FreeBSD! I am actually quite relieved that there isn't some mysterious platform magic at work here.

Comment: If you are worried about someone seeing the password, then do really want to let them see the length of it?

Comment: Security is in layers, this is yet just another.  You could say the same about any online banking or shopping site. I'm sure people wouldn't be OK with those sites showing the plain text.

Comment: Of course you're right, I was being pedantic.  It's easier just to point the hidden camera at the keyboard.

Comment: As a side point to this, you need an `stty -echo` at the beginning for the fancy version. Without that command rapid typing will leak characters onto the terminal (try holding a key for example). Using the `stty -echo` will still print the characters out, but will hide any input that didn't make it to the `read` command.

Answer (score 31):

you can use `stty` to disable echo

this solution works without bash or certain features from `read`

```
stty_orig=$(stty -g)
stty -echo
read password
stty $stty_orig
```

If you use this in a shell script then also set an exit handler which restores echo:

```
#! /bin/sh
stty_orig=$(stty -g)
trap "stty ${stty_orig}" EXIT
stty -echo
...
```

this is to make sure echo is restored regardless of how the script exits. otherwise the echo will stay off if the script errors out.

to turn echo back on manually type the following command

```
stty echo
```

you will have to type blindly because you do not see what you type.

i suggest to press ctrl+c first to clear anything else you might have typed before.

---

trivia

`echo` means to echo your typed input back to your screen.

this is from the time we worked on teletypewriters (that is what the tty means). a teletypewriter is like a typewriter but connected to another teletypewriter or computer. typically via telephone cable.

the workflow on a teletypewriter is roughly as follows: you type in your command (or message for the other side). then the teletypewriter will print the response from the other side.

when you work on a teletypewriter you see your input as you type. this is because the teletypewriter is also a typewriter and as such prints the characters as you press them.

when teletypewriters where replaced by screens there was no longer a typewriter which types your input. instead we had to deliberate code an "echo" function which prints your input as you type.

i do not know whether `stty -echo` also disabled printing on a teletypewriter.

see here for a teletypewriter in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XLZ4Z8LpEE (first part is restoration. action starting at about 12 minutes in)

more teletypewriter restoration: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-_93BVApb5-9eQLTCk9xx16RAGEYHH1q

Comment: This solution is very helpful for some implementations of the bare "sh" shell, such as Debian's dash shell.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a variation on @SiegeX's excellent `*`-printing solution for `bash` **with support for backspace** added; this allows the user to **correct their entry with the `backspace` key (`delete` key on a Mac)**, as is typically supported by password prompts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

password=''
while IFS= read -r -s -n1 char; do
  [[ -z $char ]] && { printf '\n' >/dev/tty; break; } # ENTER pressed; output \n and break.
  if [[ $char == $'\x7f' ]]; then # backspace was pressed
      # Remove last char from output variable.
      [[ -n $password ]] && password=${password%?}
      # Erase '*' to the left.
      printf '\b \b' >/dev/tty
  else
    # Add typed char to output variable.
    password+=$char
    # Print '*' in its stead.
    printf '*' >/dev/tty
  fi
done
```

Note:

- As for why pressing backspace records character code `0x7f`: "In modern systems, the backspace key is often mapped to the delete character (0x7f in ASCII or Unicode)" <sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace</sup>
- `\b \b` is needed to *give the appearance of* deleting the character to the left; just using `\b` moves the cursor to the left, but leaves the character intact (*nondestructive* backspace). By printing a space and moving back again, the character appears to have been erased (thanks, [The "backspace" escape character '\b': unexpected behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6792812/45375)).

---

In a **POSIX-only** shell (e.g., `sh` on Debian and Ubuntu, where `sh` is `dash`), **use the `stty -echo` approach** (which is suboptimal, because it prints *nothing*), because the `read` builtin will not support the `-s` and `-n` options.

Comment: @cave-at-aperture, the code already contains a check for whether the password is the empty string (`[ -n $password]`), and the `printf '\b \b'` is benign if it is.

Comment: @cave, I have improved the answer, however, by making the `printf` calls that serve the interactive input only target `/dev/tty`.

Answer (score 8):

A bit different from (but mostly like) @lesmana's answer

```
stty -echo
read password
stty echo
```

simply: hide echo
do your stuff
show echo

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than [@lesmana's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4316765/4233593)? I see it's simpler with less overhead for another `stty` call, and one less variable on the stack - only taking away echo and only restoring echo. Is there any possible way this could upset other `stty` settings? Lesmana's preserves all settings.

Comment: This answer presumes that echo was on prior to reading the user input (sometimes but not usually a safe assumption). For professional scripts, lesmana's is better.

Answer (score 4):

I always like to use Ansi escape characters:

```
echo -e "Enter your password: \x1B[8m"
echo -e "\x1B[0m"
```

`8m` makes text invisible and `0m` resets text to "normal." The -e makes Ansi escapes possible.

The only caveat is that you can still copy and paste the text that is there, so you probably shouldn't use this if you really want security.

It just lets people not look at your passwords when you type them in. Just don't leave your computer on afterwards. :)

---

NOTE:

The above is platform independent as long as it supports Ansi escape sequences.

However, for another Unix solution, you could simply tell `read` to not echo the characters...

```
printf "password: "
let pass $(read -s)
printf "\nhey everyone, the password the user just entered is $pass\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation of @SiegeX's answer which works with traditional Bourne shell (which has no support for `+=` assignments).

```
password=''
while IFS= read -r -s -n1 pass; do
  if [ -z "$pass" ]; then
     echo
     break
  else
     printf '*'
     password="$password$pass"
  fi
done
```

Comment: A traditional Bourne shell (or a POSIX-compliant one) would also not recognize `[[ ... ]]`, nor would its `read` builtin have the `-s` and `-n` options. Your code will therefore not work in `dash`, for instance. (It will work on platforms where `sh` is actually `bash`, such as on OSX, where `bash` when invoked as `sh` merely modifies a few default options while still supporting most bashisms.)

Comment: Thanks for feedback, switched to single `[` but obviously not much I can do if your `read` lacks these options.

Answer (score 1):

> Get Username and password
>
> Make it more clear to read but put it on a better position over the screen

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo 
echo 
echo
counter=0
unset username
prompt="  Enter Username:"
while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
do
    if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]; then
        break
    elif [ $char == $'\x08' ] && [ $counter -gt 0 ]; then
        prompt=$'\b \b'
        username="${username%?}"
        counter=$((counter-1))
    elif [ $char == $'\x08' ] && [ $counter -lt 1 ]; then
        prompt=''
        continue
    else
        counter=$((counter+1))
        prompt="$char"
        username+="$char"
    fi
done
echo
unset password
prompt="  Enter Password:"
while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
do
    if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]; then
        break
    elif [ $char == $'\x08' ] && [ $counter -gt 0 ]; then
        prompt=$'\b \b'
        password="${password%?}"
        counter=$((counter-1))
    elif [ $char == $'\x08' ] && [ $counter -lt 1 ]; then
        echo
        prompt="  Enter Password:"
        continue
    else
        counter=$((counter+1))
        prompt='*'
        password+="$char"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on both @SiegeX and @mklement0's excellent contributions: mask user input; handle backspacing; but only backspace for the length of what the user has input (so we're not wiping out other characters on the same line) and handle control characters, etc... This solution was found [here](https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/crypto/passwd_input.txt) after so much digging!

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Read and echo a password, echoing responsive 'stars' for input characters
# Also handles: backspaces, deleted and ^U (kill-line) control-chars
#
unset PWORD
PWORD=
echo -n 'password: ' 1>&2
while true; do
  IFS= read -r -N1 -s char
  # Note a NULL will return a empty string
  # Convert users key press to hexadecimal character code
  code=$(printf '%02x' "'$char") # EOL (empty char) -> 00
  case "$code" in
  ''|0a|0d) break ;;   # Exit EOF, Linefeed or Return
  08|7f)  # backspace or delete
      if [ -n "$PWORD" ]; then
        PWORD="$( echo "$PWORD" | sed 's/.$//' )"
        echo -n $'\b \b' 1>&2
      fi
      ;;
  15) # ^U or kill line
      echo -n "$PWORD" | sed 's/./\cH \cH/g' >&2
      PWORD=''
      ;;
  [01]?) ;;                        # Ignore ALL other control characters
  *)  PWORD="$PWORD$char"
      echo -n '*' 1>&2
      ;;
  esac
done
echo
echo $PWORD
```