# Usage of \b and \r in C

Tags: c

`\b` and `\r` are rarely used in practice. I just found out that I misunderstood these two escape sequences. A simple test:

```
printf("foo\bbar\n");
```

I expected it to output `fobar`, because `\b` will backspace the cursor, and `b` will overwrite the second `o`, but instead it outputs: `foobar`

The same is with `\r`:

```
printf("foo\rbar\n");
```

I thought `\r` will move the cursor to the beginning of the current line, so `bar` will replace `foo`, so the final output should be `bar`. However, it actually outputs:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: what platform are you on?

Comment: @Chris what does `\b` and `\r` do exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-in-c-unexpected-behavior

Comment: @suspectus I used an online gcc http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: @YuHao They don't do anything. They're just characters. But whatever you write those characters to might act a certain way when it receives those characters. e.g. if you write those characters to a file, the character will end up in the file. If you write it to a terminal/console, the terminal might erase a character when it sees the \b Some terminals would do that, some would not.

Comment: In the string it ist just ASCII 8, and 13 CR. An old smart console could have interpreted these as commands (see alse Unix curls). In general `\r` might get interpreted as line break. _In fact you found the two most useless characters._

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The characters will get send just like that to the underlying output device (in your case probably a terminal emulator).

It is up to the terminal's implementation then how those characters get actually displayed. For example, a bell (`\a`) could trigger a beep sound on some terminals, a flash of the screen on others, or it will be completely ignored. It all depends on how the terminal is configured.

Comment: do you know how to configure mine so it doesnt ignore the bell(\a) ??

Comment: In Windows 10, when I opened it using the terminal, I heard the same sound as when Notepad asks if you want to save, and then you click out of the pop-up. When I opened the executable with two clicks or with PowerShell, I got the error message sound.

Answer (score 12):

The characters are exactly as documented - `\b` equates to a character code of `0x08` and `\r` equates to `0x0d`. The thing that varies is how your OS reacts to those characters. Back when displays were trying to emulate an old teletype those actions were standardized, but they are less useful in modern environments and compatibility is not guaranteed.

Comment: Tthe standard doesn't say what the character codes are.  `\b` will be `0x08` only if `0x08` corresponds to the backspace character in the execution character set (which is true in ASCII and Unicode and other common character sets).  If your execution character set is EBCDIC, however, then `\b` will map to `\0x16` (if I can trust the character tables I'm finding online).

Answer (score 5):

The interpretation of the backspace and carriage return characters is left to the software you use for display. A terminal emulator, when displaying \b would move the cursor one step back, and when displaying \r to the beginning of the line. If you print these characters somewhere else, like a text file, the software may choose. to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

I have experimented many of the backslash escape characters. `\n` which is a new line feed can be put anywhere to bring the effect. One important thing to remember while using this character is that the operating system of the machine we are using might affect the output. As an example, I have printed a bunch of escape character and displayed the result as follow to proof that the OS will affect the output.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("Hello World!");
    printf("Goodbye \a");
    printf("Hi \b");
    printf("Yo\f");
    printf("What? \t");
    printf("pewpew");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Codes should be text , you can insert images for output which can't be posted here obviously as it won't display as it would on local machines

Answer (score 1):

As for the meaning of each character described in C Primer Plus, what you expected is an 'correct' answer. It should be true for some computer architectures and compilers, but unfortunately not yours.

I wrote a simple c program to repeat your test, and got that 'correct' answer. I was using Mac OS and gcc.
[image]

Also, I am very curious what is the compiler that you were using. :)

Answer (score 1):

In different compilers, backslash escape characters behave differently.

In MAC OS with clang `\b` takes off the last char from the console as you expected.

```
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{
  std::cout << "Test";
  std::cout << "\b";
  std::cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 Tes
```