# Escape sequences are producing unexpected output in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C programming language, recently I have studied about **escape sequence**.

```
\n means newline
\b means backspace
\r means carriage-return
```

When I am applying these on the following program, then I am getting output as **hai**, Can anyone please explain, how?

```
main()
{
    printf("\nab");
    printf("\bsi");
    printf("\rha");
}
```

Comment: Your assumption may not be true, and the output may varies, see [Usage of \b and \r in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17236242/1009479)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\r` is actually carriage return (which takes the cursor to the start of the line).

Your program outputs a new line (`\n`) followed by "ab" then backspace (`\b`) (over the b) "si", so you now have "asi" on the screen.
The `\r` takes the cursor to the start of the line and then outputs "ha" leaving "hai" on the screen.

Answer (score 5):

The first instruction will print `ab` on a **new line** (`\n`) :

```
>ab
```

The second instruction will make a **backspace** (`\b`) before printing `si` :

```
>asi
```

Then the last one will make a **carriage return** (`\r`) before printing `ha` :

```
>hai
```

Answer (score 4):

First `printf` will print `ab` then `\b` will make backspace and print `si` so your final print becomes `asi`.

Now in last `\r` will move the cursor at beginning and prints `ha` which will replace first two character and makes final string as `hai`(`ha` from last statement and `i` from earlier result.)

Answer (score 3):

Because you are writing everything on the same line after the first `\n` :

```
 printf( "\nab" ); // -> ab on a new line
```

**Line status : `ab`**

```
 printf( "\bsi" );
```

It means `ab` minus the `b` because of the **backspace** then you add `si` to the line.

**Line status : `asi`**

Finally :

```
 printf( "\rha" );
```

Means that you go back at the beginning of the line and write `ha`.

**It leads to `hai`.**

---

`\r` is *carriage-return*, not *linefeed*.

Answer (score 2):

No, `'\r'` is *not* linefeed, `'\n'` is actually linefeed. It just happens to be so that many modern systems uses `'\n'` as both linefeed and carriage-return, making it "newline".

`'\r'` is *carriage-return*, which returns the cursor to the start of the line.

Answer (score 1):

> **\b is for backspace.** That is, it removes the character just written.
>   
>  **\r is to return the cursor back to the left most position in the
>   current line.**

Let z represent cursor.

After statement one.

```
\n
abz
```

After backspace.

```
az
```

After statement two.

```
asiz
```

After return.

```
zbi
```

After statement three

`haiz`

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code

1. **\r**

   ```
   \r means Carriage Return, which means: return the cursor to the beginning of the line in more simple words we can say that it's deleting each character from the active position upto the beginning.
   ```
2. **\n**

   ```
   \n mean New Line
   ```
3. **\b**

   ```
   \b mean Backspace
   ```

Let's take it one step at a time:

```
<new line>ab<backspace>si<carriage return>ha
```

First, handle the backspace. Note that even though it is "non-erase", the next character to be output would overwrite what was backspaced over:

```
<new line>asi<carriage return>ha
```

Now, a carriage return means to go back to the beginning of the line. So the "ha" overwrites the "as" in "asi:

```
<new line>hai
```

Now, the cursor is currently sitting on the i, so the next character to be output would overwrite i.