# How to use printf() and scanf() in C without going to the next line?

Tags: c, output, scanf, newline

I want to get date of birth in one line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int BirthYear,BirthMonth,BirthDay;
    printf("Please enter your birth date: ");
    scanf("%d",&BirthYear);
    printf("/");
    scanf("%d",&BirthMonth);
    printf("/");
    scanf("%d",&BirthDay);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
Please enter your birth date: YYYY
/MM
/DD
```

But I want to get something like this:

```
Please enter your birth date: YYYY/MM/DD
```

In output, it goes to next line after each scanf() without using \n.
I use VS Code for IDM.

Comment: so why don't you write "Pleaser enter your birth date in format Y/m/d" and then read it with fgets, sscanf?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need to get date as I wrote.

Comment: Why do you need that? And what's the problem with newlines?

Comment: The newline is coming from you having to hit Enter for each input - you can't do what you want with plain C.

Comment: You probably need something like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), but this might be beyond your scope for the moment. Is this for homework?

Comment: String parsing.

Comment: Thank you all, If this is because I press the Enter button, there is no way for a line to go back (something opposite \n) after pressing Enter and then scanf()?

Comment: @ParsaSaberi yes you've got it. In standarfd C there is no way.

Comment: `scanf("%d/%d/%d", &y, &m, &d)` would be much simpler

Comment: The problem is not in your C at all.  There are comments here saying "you can't do that in C", and that's not quite correct.  What you cannot easily do in C is use a tty to provide the input to your program while simultaneously changing the default behavior of your tty.  But if you don't try to use a tty to provide input interactively to your program, you will have no problem at all.

Comment: In other words: `echo 2011 01 07 | ./a.out` will not generate the unwanted newlines.

Comment: OT: `YYYY/MM/DD` is not a great format since `/` is also used for the `DD/MM/YYYY` and `MM/DD/YYYY` format. Better would be `YYYY-MM-DD` (ISO8603).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a workaround using ansi control characters. I would not do like this, but just to show that it is possible:

```
#define PREVLINE "\033[F"
#define MSG "Please enter your birth date: "

int main(void) {
    int BirthYear,BirthMonth,BirthDay;
    
    printf(MSG);
    scanf("%d",&BirthYear);
    printf(PREVLINE MSG "%d/", BirthYear);
    scanf("%d",&BirthMonth);
    printf(PREVLINE MSG "%d/%d/", BirthYear, BirthMonth);
    scanf("%d",&BirthDay);
    printf("You entered: %d/%d/%d\n", BirthYear, BirthMonth, BirthDay);
}
```

Please note that this is not portable. The terminal needs to support this in order to work. AFAIK there's no 100% portable way to achieve this.

If you want to do this stuff for real, then I recommend taking a look at [the ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Note:

Always check the return value for `scanf` to detect errors.

Note2:

It may be a good idea to add `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf` statement.

I actually wrote another answer today about ascii control characters. It might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64549313/6699433

Comment: @AdrianMole Smellier than using ascii control characters? Don't think so... :D

Comment: @ParsaSaberi Don't know if it is helpful to be honest. I would really, REALLY try to avoid things like this. :D

Comment: `"\033[F"` are not ascii control characters - aside from escape, but an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Embarasing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly specify that the three input numbers should be separated by a `'/'` character by adding that character in the format specifier for the `scanf` function.

Then, you can ensure that the user gave valid input by checking the value returned by `scanf` (which will be the number of items successfully scanned and assigned); if that value is not `3`, then you will (probably) need to clear any 'leftover' characters in the input buffer, using a `getchar()` loop until a newline (or end-of-file) is found:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int BirthYear, BirthMonth, BirthDay;
    int nIns = 0, ch;
    while (nIns != 3) {
        printf("Enter D.O.B. (as YYYY/MM/DD): ");
        nIns = scanf("%d/%d/%d", &BirthYear, &BirthMonth, &BirthDay);
        while ((ch = getchar() != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            ; // Clear remaining in-buffer on error
    }
    printf("Entered data were: %d %d %d!\n", BirthYear, BirthMonth, BirthDay);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what the OP wants but it's probbaly the closest you can get to it using standard c.

Comment: Suggest a more tolerant `"%d /%d /%d"`.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment...

The problem you're running into is that you have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> for each input, which writes a newline to the terminal screen.  You can't avoid that.

And unfortunately, you can't overwrite the newline on the screen with a `'\b'`; you can only backspace up to the beginning of the current line, not to a previous line.

You basically can't do what you want with vanilla C - the language only sees byte streams, it has no concept of a "screen".

There are some [terminal control sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) you can play with to reposition the cursor after sending the newline; I don't know how well those will work for you.

Beyond that, you'll need to use a library like [`ncurses`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int BirthYear,BirthMonth,BirthDay;
    printf("Please enter your birth date: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&BirthYear,&BirthMonth,&BirthDay);
    return 0;
}
```

You can take multiple values from `scanf` which are then separated by any text you like (in this case `/`s).

Comment: And what if the user just enters `1977[Enter]`?

Comment: 1977 will be taken as the value of birthyear. And the month and day value will be a garbage value.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) (in particular before all calls to [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)) like in

```
printf("Please enter your birth date: ");
fflush(NULL);
```

but you should read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website, a good book about C programming such as [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), and the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

Consider enabling all warnings and debug info in your compiler. With `gcc`  that means compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Be aware that [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) can fail.

### Your code and problem is surely [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) specific.

On Linux consider using [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html) (for a terminal interface) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/) (for a graphical interface). Read also [the tty demystified](https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/), then [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html).

You might also consider using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), but be aware that in 2020 [UTF-8 should be used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: Even the page you linked to has this: *but not pipes or terminals* for `fflush()`.