# Usage of \b in Perl

Tags: perl, backspace

the \b "bakspace in perl doesn't works when we use it at the last of the string.

Eg: If we see the code, i have written

```
print "Hello\n";    
print "Hello\n";
print "\bHe\bllo\b";
```

It gives me this output:

Hello Hell**o** Hll**o**

So should the highlighted oo be deleted or in case, the \n would have been deleted taking the control to the 2nd line?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder answer at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-in-c-unexpected-behavior): "Your result will vary depending on what kind of terminal or console program you're on, but yes, on most \b is a nondestructive backspace. It moves the cursor backward, but doesn't erase what's there."

Answer (score 5):

`\b` is a shorthand for `\x08`, so

```
print "a\b";
```

simply outputs bytes

```
61 08
```

Most terminals interpret `08` as a request to move the cursor one position to the left. If you want to "erase" a character, you need to overwrite it with another.

```
print "a\b \b";
```