# KR - visualize backspace

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I come across this KR exercise 1-10:

> Write a program to copy its input to its output, replace each tab by \t, each backspace by \b, and each backslash by \\ .

Here's a very simple solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    const char TAB = '\t';
    const char BACKSPACE = '\b';
    const char BACKSLASH = '\\';
    while( EOF != ( c = getchar() ) )
    {
        if( TAB == c )
        {
            printf( "\\t" );
        }
        else if( BACKSPACE == c )
        {
            printf( "\\b" );
        }
        else if( BACKSLASH == c )
        {
            printf( "\\\\" );
        }
        else
        {
            putchar( c );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I found the it works ok to visualize <kbd>Tab</kbd> and `\` (Backslash) but not <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Looks like <kbd>Backspace</kbd>s are not remembered by the console? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-in-c-unexpected-behavior) seems a similar issue, but not quite sure it's the same.

Comment: You're right. Your code is fine, it's the terminal that's more advanced than this hypothetical scenario.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but `c` should be an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: yeah thanks - fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you run your program in a terminal and then type some input.
The terminal is usually in **cooked mode**, where a backspace would be immediately interpreted as *please erase the previous character*. The `getchar()` wouldn't ever return a backspace.

If you want to test your program for proper handling of backspaces, *pipe* them in on standard input, this cirumvents the use of a terminal with the associated cooking:

```
 $ printf 'foo\bbar\n' | ./a.out
 foo\bbar
```

Comment: Yeah I tested it over terminal, and indeed backspace was never stored.

Btw, any reading recommendation for the `cooked mode` terminal?

Comment: @artm What constitutes cooked mode (and all other terminal settings) is usually found in the `stty(1)` manual page.