# Why BACKSPACE (\b) does not work as intended with a file?

Tags: c, file, printf, backspace

I opened a (text) file, like so: `File *fp = fopen("findPattern2.txt", "w+");` in which i have written text. The last character i have in there is a `,`. Now i want to delete that character using backspace. I've read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-in-c-unexpected-behavior/6793113) that BACKSPACE only moves the cursor, then i have to overwrite that character by writing on top of it and this is what i do. So I did `fprintf(fp, "\b \b")` to completely erase the `,`, but instead this is what the file shows afterwards:`,BS BS`. All of these work with a terminal. Why not with a file?

From what I gather the only way to do this to a file would be if i memory mapped it, edit its contents, copy them to a new file and delete the old one.

Comment: Have you tried using `fseek` or `fsetpos`?

Comment: I asked because question says *"From what I gather the only way to do this to a file would be if i memory mapped it, edit its contents, copy them to a new file and delete the old one."*. That sentence makes it sound like you want solution, but your comment indicates you want just explanation. You should [edit] your question to make it clear what you expect from the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file is just a collection of bytes that when read in by a program produce  (possibly) meaningful results like a picture or video or whatever. Unless the program knows that a backspace character should delete the proceeding character, it won't do anything.

Your terminal is a program that has been written in just that way to react to special characters like backspace and knows what to do when it receives one though.

Answer (score 3):

If you "printf" the `BS` character to the terminal, the latter interprets this so the cursor will be moved to the left.

But if you "fprintf" the `BS` character to a file, then the `BS` character (which is just a byte) will simply be written into the file.

Answer (score 2):

Cursors and line editing are things that consoles and terminals have, not files.

You seem to misunderstand how files work.

There's simply no concept of editing inside a file, it's a sequence of bytes. You can overwrite by using `fseek()` to move the current location (sometimes called "the cursor" but that's an analogy, it doesn't mean files act like text editors) and then writing the new data.