# How '\b' works in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why the result of `print('helloo\b')` is not `hello` and also result of `print('heeee\b\b\blo')` is not `hello`?

The answers are `helloo` and `heloe`.

Comment: The behavior depends on what you use to view the result, such as your terminal or tools like less. Python has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Note that `"hello!\b?" != "hello?"`, the `\b` has an effect during `print` but not on the content of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the result of print('helloo\b') is not 'hello'

Because `\b` does not remove characters, it just moves the cursor back one position. Since there is nothing after the `\b`, nothing was overwritten. You end up with something like:

```
hello
    ^
```

Where `^` is the cursor.

> and also result of print('heeee\b\b\blo') is not 'hello? the answers are 'helloo' and 'heloe'

Because in this you did move the cursor back 3 positions and wrote `lo` over the second and third `e`s:

```
heeee
  ^
```

Becomes:

```
heloe
```

---

Note that all this is about *printing* the string somewhere like a terminal that recognizes the backspace character (given what you mention that you "see" in the question) -- the string in memory is still the same, including the `\b` characters. See e.g. [The "backspace" escape character '\b': unexpected behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-unexpected-behavior) as well.