# String in c "Hello world"?

Tags: c, string, obfuscation

I dont understand how the word "word" is printed in line 5. Can somebody explain to me?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) {
        char str[50] = "hello\0 worl\bd";
        printf("\n %s ",str);
        printf("%s \n",str+str[4]-*str);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `\b` does a backspace. So `d` overwrites `l`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "backspace" escape character '\b': unexpected behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: And `str+str[4]-*str` is just `str+7`.

Comment: @Blaze can you explain why?

Comment: `*str` is `'h'`, `str[4]` is `'o'`,  `'o' - 'h'` is `7`.

Answer (score 3):

So, step-by-step:

- **"str"** points to your string `"hello\0 worl\bd"`, which is actually `"hello\0 word"` (since \b deletes the previous character)
- ***str =** is the the "content" of your char pointer, which means the first character of your string, that is "h"
- **str[4] =** is the (4+1)th character of str, that is `'o'`
- **str[4] - *str =** `'o'-'h'` = 7 *(but why is it 7? 'h' has an ASCII character value of 104 and 'o' a value of 111)*
- **str + 7 =** str[7]

---

So, you are basically printing the string starting at index:7 of your initial string.

Hence: `'word'` ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of All the String as under:

```
 0 => h
 1 => e
 2 => l
 3 => l
 4 => o
 5 => \0
 6 => (space bar)
 7 => w
 8 => o
 9 => r
10 => l
11 => \b
12 => d
```

now your command is:

```
printf("%s \n",str+str[4]-*str);
```

C has done the following thing

```
 str => point of starting printing

 str[4] as above is o

 *str as above is h

 Thus o - h = 7 [i.e. ascii value 111 - 104]

 printing would starting from character 7 i.e. [str+7]
```