# Adding something after \b in printf() to make it work

Tags: c, printf

I found out that I have to add something, at least a space or any character/number, after \b in printf() to make it work, why?

```
printf("hello\b ");
```

Comment: to make what work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "backspace" escape character '\b': unexpected behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: Backspace moves the cursor position back one position (with caveats about what happens at the beginning of a line); it does not erase what is currently at the position.