# Saving to file without printing on screen, using a bash script

Tags: bash, file, logging, console, echo

Using a bash script, how do you save information in a file, without printing it on the console?
I've written a script that requires the user to enter a value. This value has to be logged in a text file, without printing it on screen. So far I've written:

```
echo "x = " 
read v_x 
echo $v_x > temp.txt
```

but that prints it on the screen as well as saving it in the file.

Comment: So you mean when user writes it you do not want it to appear in screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I echo stars (\*) when reading password with \`read\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923435/how-do-i-echo-stars-when-reading-password-with-read)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make bash script ask for a password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654009/how-to-make-bash-script-ask-for-a-password)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-s` option for read:

```
read -s v_x
```

`help read` tells:

```
  -s        do not echo input coming from a terminal
```

Comment: No, this isn't what my problem is. I don't want to hide what the user is typing, while he's typing it. The problem, I think, lies with the `echo` command. The line `echo $v_x > temp.txt` prints on the console screen as well as in the file, so the number the user just entered get repeated on screen after he hits 'return'.

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiev Saying `echo $v_x > temp.txt` redirects the `STDOUT` to the file `temp.txt`.  That would __not__ produce any output on the terminal.

Comment: Well, that's what I thought too. I have no idea why it happens but it does repeat the same number and its not from the `read`. Thanks anyway. I found a way around that problem.